# Converting object to dictionary key

Tags: python, string, dictionary, object, hashmap

I was wondering if there is an easy way to essentially have multiple keys in a dictionary for one value. An example of what I would like to achieve is as following:

```py
class test:
    key="test_key"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.key

tester = test()

dictionary = {}
dictionary[tester] = 1

print(dictionary[tester])
print(dictionary["test_key"])
```

where the output would be:

```py
>>> 1
>>> 1
```

What I'm looking for is a way to automatically convert the object to a string before its used as a key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I think it's better to explicitly cast the object to a string, e.g.

```py
dictionary[str(tester)] = 1
```

That being said, if you're *really* ***really*** ***REALLY*** sure you want to do this, define the `__hash__` and `__eq__` dunder methods. No need to create a new data structure or change the existing code outside of the class definition:

```py
class test:
    key="test_key"
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.key == other
        return self.key == other.key
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

This will output:

```py
1
1
```

Comment: This is very good, with an obvious caveat that the class `test` is now changed with consequences beyond dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what im looking for. There are some consequences but they shouldn't pose a large problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain you should not do this; just use `dictionary[str(tester)]`. It is more readable, less surprises, only five characters more to write.

If you insist though, this is the best I can think of

```
class StrKeyedDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(str(key))
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(str(key), value)
    # ... do all the other methods that mess with the key

class Test:
    key="test_key"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key

tester = Test()
dictionary = StrKeyedDict()
dictionary[tester] = 1
print(dictionary["test_key"])
# => 1
```